# Inner join tabela join com vários IDs iguais

Tags: mysql, join, inner

O problema é seguinte, tenho duas tabelas uma de contratos e outra de mutuários 1xN e quando faço o `inner join` ele repete exatamente a quantidade de colunas que tenho em mutuário mas só traz o nome do primeiro. segue exemplo:

```
select 
    co.id,
    ....
form 
   contratos ct
inner join
   os ss on (ss.contratos_id=ct.id)
inner join
   mutuarios mt on (mt.contratos_id=ct.id)
where....
```

Espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: publique sua query para que possamos analisar.

Comment: @Augusto não esqueça de aceitar a resposta que lhe melhor convier como correta (V abaixo das setas do lado esquerdo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é o comportamento normal de um `INNER JOIN` ele faz a associação dos registros de uma tabela com aqueles equivalentes na outra.

Se na tabela `contratos` você tem 1 registro e na mutuários 10 registros ligados a esse `contrato`, um `inner join` entre elas irá mostrar 10 registros repetindo os campos que você colocou referente a tabela contratos

Na sua consulta, você está usando um alias que não foi definido `co.` nas suas tabelas `from`

No seu caso você tem o `INNER JOIN` entre três tabelas, então a quantidade de registros será a equivalência entre elas. No seu caso específico, se você tiver 1 contrato, 3 `os` desse contrato e 3 `mutuários` desse contrato você deverá ver 9 registros. Ou seja a combinação entre as três tabelas:

Veja esse exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/addef/3

Você vai ver que você tem para cada registro de `A` (no exemplo) a combinação de `B` e `C`

Se você quiser que apenas o contrato apareça, sem especificar nenhum dos registro que são duplicados utilize a cláusula `DISTINCT` na sua query:

```
select DISTINCT
    ct.id,
    ....
from
   contratos ct
inner join
   os ss on (ss.contratos_id=ct.id)
inner join
   mutuarios mt on (mt.contratos_id=ct.id)
where....
```

É importante lembrar que o `DISTINCT` eliminará apenas o que for duplicado para o escopo das colunas do `select`, ou seja `ct.id, ....`

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o erro foi meu, eu estava agrupando e não conseguia visualizar os outros mutuários. Obrigado a todos pela atenção